# formal names of fields in dis.dis(foo)

Tags: python

I have the following codes,

```
In [4]: def foo():
   ...:     a = 2
   ...:     b = 3
   ...:     return a + b
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [5]: import dis

In [6]: dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             12 BINARY_ADD
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Reference to the bytecodes:
I know that:
the first column is line-number: 2, 3, 4 
the third column is op-names: LOAD_CONST etc
the fifth column is the codes: (2) (a)

How about the second column: 0, 2 4, 6, 8...
and the fourth column 1, 0, 2, 1

Could you please provide a hint to find related info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column is the bytecode byte index; each bytecode consists of 2 bytes (one indicating the exact opcode, the other the opcode argument value). It is actually column #4; there are two columns with no current value in your output.

For your function, you can find the bytestring that contains the bytecode as the `__code__.co_code` attribute:

```
>>> foo.__code__.co_code
b'd\x01}\x00d\x02}\x01|\x00|\x01\x17\x00S\x00'
```

So `b'd\x01'` is `LOAD_CONST 1`, `b'}\x00'` is `STORE_FAST 0`, etc.

This is documented under the [`dis.disco()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.disco):

> The output is divided in the following columns:
>
> 1. the line number, for the first instruction of each line
> 2. the current instruction, indicated as `-->`,
> 3. a labelled instruction, indicated with `>>`,
> 4. the address of the instruction,
> 5. the operation code name,
> 6. operation parameters, and
> 7. interpretation of the parameters in parentheses.

When you use `dis.dis()`, column #2 (*current instruction*) will always be empty.

Column #3, the labelled instruction, is used whenever there's a loop or test. For example:

```
>>> dis.dis('if foo:\n    for i in it:\n        print(i)\nelse: print(bar)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       28

  2           4 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 36)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (it)
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (i)

  3          14 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             16 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK
             26 JUMP_FORWARD             8 (to 36)

  4     >>   28 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             30 LOAD_NAME                4 (bar)
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             34 POP_TOP
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

There are 4 jump targets, where several opcodes can trigger a jump to one of those positions. They serve as a visual marker to ease reading.

Comment: could I ask what's the `d` in `d\x01`, and '}` in ''}\x00'`?

Comment: It’s the ASCII representation of the byte that Python interprets as the specific bytecode. So `d` is 0x64 in hex, and the Python interpreter evaluation loop will execute it as the `LOAD_CONST` opcode.

Comment: You can use the `dis.opmap` dictionary to map opcode names to bytes. Or use the `dis.opname` list with the integer value of the byte to find the name; e.g. `dis.opname[0x64]`.